# Global Pointcloud-Registration on RoomScan-Data

Tags: computer-vision, point-clouds, open3d

I have two pointclouds of different size and now the second pointcloud should be aligned with the first pointcloud.
So the first pointcloud is a LIDAR_Scan of a room:
[First Pointcloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvw8J.png)

The second pointcloud is the pointcloud of the whole floor:
[Second Pointcloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i0Fc.png)

Now I want to determine the transformation-matrix T for the 2nd pointcloudn s. t. the 2nd pointcloud fits the 1st pointcloud best.

I've already produced the Transformation-Matrix T by hand so I manually set the optimal values for T and this is the result which I want to produce by a registration algorithm:
[Best Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMm7R.png)

I've implemented many available methods from

> open3d such as the
> o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_ransac_based_on_feature_matching
>
> o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_fgr_based_on_feature_matching
>
> o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_fgr_based_on_correspondence
> and also the registration algorithm from TEASER++ but non of them
> produced the expected solution as in the picture above.

Is there any other method which I could try out or a paper which handles this problem?

Comment: you might try *6D pose estimation* pipelines which uses instance segmentation to do the initial localization, e.g. [GDR](https://github.com/THU-DA-6D-Pose-Group/GDR-Net)